# How does stopping service affect the thread created with in the service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

I am creating an app which require a service. This service create a thread and called **selfStop** immediately.

How does stopping the service affect the life cycle of created thread?

Is there anyway to stop the service from the thread, if the service is running?

Can a service be stopped after some delay, if it is running?

Thanks!

Comment: If the process in which the service is created is alive, the thread stays on.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new thread which processes something in the background, it will be destroyed automatically after this process ends up.

It does not make sense to create a thread and try to stop the main thread from it.

Comment: But the service will still keep running.

Comment: when you talk about "service" are you meaning the main thread?